# Short blockquotes don't get indented?

Tags: indentation, csquotes

I am using the csquotes package for my blockquotes. I want them to be indented regardless of length, but its not working for short ones (~3 lines), only for longer ones.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,ngerman]{report}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\section{}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
Integer a purus vel lacus eleifend feugiat sed id eros. 

 %This doesn't get indented
\blockquote{It is through a learning process inclusive of critical reflection, seeking out new skills and knowledge, action, and discourse that the stranger interprets the meaning of his or her experience and develops intercultural competence.}

 %This does
\blockquote{\lipsum[1]}

\end{document}
```

Strangely enough, the first one gets surrounding quotes, while the second doesn't.

Is there an option to control this behaviour?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

From `csquotes` manual (page 6 an 7)

> This command determines the length of the h text i . If the length
>   exceeds a certain threshold, the h text i will be typeset in display
>   mode, i.e., as a block quotation. If not, \blockquote will behave like
>   \textquote . Depending on the thresholdtype option, the threshold may
>   be based on the number of lines required to typeset the 6 h text i or
>   on the number of words in the h text i . If the parthreshold option
>   has been enabled, any explicit paragraph or line break in the h text i
>   will trigger the thres- hold, i.e., it will be typeset in display mode
>   regardless of its length. The default threshold setup is three lines
>   with parthreshold enabled. The default environ- ment used for display
>   quotations is the quote environment.

You can get out of this by specifing `threshold=<number of lines>` in `\usepackage[threshold=1]{csquotes}`. You can also use `\SetBlockThreshold{1}`. Other relevant commands in this connection are

```
thresholdtype= lines , words      %% decide lines or words for threshold
```

and

```
parthreshold=true, false          %% detect paragraph end for threshold
```

Refer section 8.6 in the manual for additional information.

Full code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,ngerman]{report}
%\usepackage[threshold=1]{csquotes}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\section{}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
Integer a purus vel lacus eleifend feugiat sed id eros.
\SetBlockThreshold{1}     %% this can also be used
 %This does get indented too
\blockquote{It is through a learning process inclusive of critical reflection,
 seeking out new skills and knowledge, action, and discourse that the stranger 
interprets the meaning of his or her experience and develops intercultural 
competence.}

 %This does
\blockquote{\lipsum[1]}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I believe there's something more: the second blockquote is indented also if `\lipsum*[1]` is used, which doesn't add a final `\par`. If I double the OP's text, it gets indented.

Comment: @egreg Got it. I will edit. :-)

Comment: `thresholdtype`, `threshold` and `parthreshold` package options.

Comment: @egreg While `SetBlockThreshold` works fine, it applies to everything afterwards. Is there a clean way to only force display mode for one blockquote? (The author's account was deleted, that's why I ping you, hope you don't mind.)

Comment: @ComFreek Use a group?